# Array won't assign more than 8 characters in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Array is acting weirdly, I have this code:

```
a=np.array(['dfdfdfdf', 'gulf', 'egypt', 'hijazi a', 'gulf', 'egypt'])
```

And I did this:

```
a[0]="hello there my friend"
```

Result was:

```
array(['hello th', 'gulf', 'egypt', 'hijazi a', 'gulf', 'egypt'],
      dtype='<U8')
```

What exactly is going on?

Comment: `u8` means 8 characters (8*4=32 bytes).

Comment: Your dtype is: `'<U8'`, so everything after character 8 gets truncated

Comment: how to fix it? I want it longer

Comment: @knh190 actually, it's unicode, so the itemsize is 8*4 bytes, or 32

Comment: @JohnSall you can set a larger size for your dtype, or use `object` dtype, but why do you want to use a `numpy.ndarray` anyway? Why not just a regular `list`?

Comment: The official doc about [dtype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it by using `dtype` parameter to a very big number (e.g. `100`):

```
>>> a=np.array(['dfdfdfdf', 'gulf', 'egypt', 'hijazi a', 'gulf', 'egypt'],dtype='<U100')
>>> a[0] = "hello there my friend"
>>> a
array(['hello there my friend', 'gulf', 'egypt', 'hijazi a', 'gulf',
       'egypt'], 
      dtype='<U100')
>>>
```

Or use:

```
>>> a=np.array(['dfdfdfdf', 'gulf', 'egypt', 'hijazi a', 'gulf', 'egypt'],dtype='<U100')
>>> a.dtype = '<U100'
>>> a[0] = "hello there my friend"
>>> a
array(['hello there my friend', 'gulf', 'egypt', 'hijazi a', 'gulf',
       'egypt'], 
      dtype='<U100')
>>>
```

Comment: can I change the dtype of an array var that already defined?

Comment: @JohnSall see the second part, i edited my answer

Comment: I'm changing "<U8" to "<U32" and it gives me this error:
ValueError: When changing to a larger dtype, its size must be a divisor of the total size in bytes of the last axis of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The default `dtype` of an array of strings will be calculated based on the string with maximum length. In your case `dtype='<U8'`.

You'd have to define the `dtype` according to the length of the new string that you want to insert into the array.

You could do something like:

```
s = np.array(["hello there my friend"])
a = np.array(['dfdfdfdf', 'gulf', 'egypt', 'hijazi a', 'gulf', 'egypt'], \
              dtype=s.dtype) 

a[0] = "hello there my friend"

print(a)
array(['hello there my friend', 'gulf', 'egypt', 'hijazi a', 'gulf',
   'egypt'], dtype='<U21')
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modify-numpy-array-to-store-an-arbitrary-length-string/).

```
a=np.array(['dfdfdfdf', 'gulf', 'egypt', 'hijazi a', 'gulf', 'egypt'], dtype = 'object')
```